# I don't understand how default values work in inheritence

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am new to OOP and working on an example:

```
class Vehicle (object):

    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, mileage):
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity):
        return f"The seating capacity of a {self.name} is {capacity} passengers"


class Bus(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, mileage):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, name, max_speed, mileage)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Brand: {self.name}, Maximum Speed: {self.max_speed} MPH, Mileage: {self.mileage}"

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity = 50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity = 60)

b = Bus("a", 190, 29)

print(b.seating_capacity())
```

Here, I don't understand which default value of capacity is preferred. For example when I just write:

```
def seating_capacity(self, capacity = 50):
    return super().seating_capacity(capacity = 60)
```

I get `"The seating capacity of a a is 60 passengers"` so this implies `super().seating_capacity(capacity = 60)` Has more preference and `def seating_capacity(self, capacity = 50)` is just a fallback value, right?

Then when I try:

```
def seating_capacity(self, capacity):
    return super().seating_capacity(capacity = 60)
```

According to my understanding, In this case there is no need of fall back value. Yet I get, `*TypeError: seating_capacity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capacity'`.

Comment: 60 is not a default value, it's the actual argument to the function. Please check how keyword arguments work.

Comment: You never use the `capacity` parameter of your method, and call the parent's method with the argument 60 explicitely, so there's nothing special happening here. You would get exactly the same with ordinary functions, without classes/inheritance/whatever.

Comment: In your last example, `b` is a `Bus`, and it's `seating_capacity` method has no default value for `capacity`, so you have to pass a value for it.

Comment: Default values are not subject to inheritance *at all*. Inheritance only defines the method resolution *order* ("what ``super`` defers to"), but calling the actual methods follows the exact same rules as calling functions. Defining a new version of a method in a subclass does not change the method in the baseclass, it merely puts a new method in front of the old; the two just happen to have the same unqualified name.

Comment: Thanks all! I understood this. Thanks again for your time and effort everyone :)